# Android volley get request does not work on first time

Tags: android, android-volley, getjson

I would like to send a new `JsonObjectRequest` request (GET)

Here is my code below:

```
    final VolleyApplication volleyApplication = VolleyApplication.getInstance();
        volleyApplication.init(getApplicationContext());

        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest("http://localhost:8080/webapi/", new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                try {
                    VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                    System.out.print(response.toString());
                    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();
                    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<MyEntity>>() {
                    }.getType();
                    myList = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), listType);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
                , new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                System.out.print(error.getMessage());
            }
        }
        );
RequestQueue requestQueue = volleyApplication.getRequestQueue();
        requestQueue.add(req);
```

this works on `onCreate` and list some object but it does not. As i see in debug mode,process works two times for this method. In first time when it is at `RequestQueue requestQueue = volleyApplication.getRequestQueue(); requestQueue.add(req);`.... line
it jumps out to end of the method. But it works and gets data for second time. This messed up my code.

And also my VolleyApplication class here below

```
public final class VolleyApplication {

    private static VolleyApplication instance = null;


    public static final VolleyApplication getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new VolleyApplication();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private boolean initialized = false;

    private VolleyApplication() {
    }

    public void init(final Context context) {
        if (initialized) {
            return;
        }

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        int memory = ((ActivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getMemoryClass();
        int cacheSize = 1024 * 1024 * memory / 8;

        // imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue, new BitmapLruCache(cacheSize));
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Init first");
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        if (imageLoader == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Init first");
        }
        return imageLoader;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@seradd

You are interpreting it wrong.

It is actually executing only one time.
What you are seeing in debug mode is that,

First time it is creating `requestObject` and adding it  to `RequestQueue`.
`RequestQueue` then execute it and once it will get response from URL it will execute its callback functions `onResponse()` and `onErrorResponse()` from `Response.Listener` and `Response.ErrorListener` interface respectively.

> So what I suggest you , whatever task you are doing after adding task
>   to RequestQueue call add that code to `onResponse()` method

Comment: @Guarav sir i 'm facing the same issue.. can you elaborate this in more detail, your quote: "So what I suggest you , whatever task you are doing after adding task to RequestQueue call that code from onResponse()"

Comment: @xamMTS `onResponse()` will get called after you got response from server, So if you are dependent on response add that code, let say update UI. into `onResponse()` method